# Elastic Search - Performing Geo Location Query on Bulk imported JSON

Tags: geolocation, elasticsearch

I have a file **modified.json** containing JSON documents which contain the following:

```
{"index":{"_index": "trial", "_type": "trial", "_id":"1"}}
{"clinics" : [{"price": 1048, "city": "Bangalore", "Location": {"lon": 77.38381692924742, "lat": 12.952155989068519}}, {"price": 1048, "city": "Bangalore", "Location": {"lon": 77.38381692924742, "lat": 12.952155989068519}}]
```

.... And more similar documents. I am running a bulk insert through this command:

```
curl -s -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/_bulk' --data-binary @modified.json
```

Next, through the **Sense (Google Chrome)** plugin, I am issuing the following request

Server: localhost:9200/trial/trial

```
PUT _search
{
    "mappings": {
        "clinics": {
            "properties": {
                "Location": {"type": "geo_point"}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know whether or not this is creating a mapping for the Location fields. 
After issuing a search request, like this:

Server: localhost:9200/trial/trial

```
GET _search
{
    "query": {
        "filtered" : {
            "query" : {
                "match_all" : {}
            },
            "filter" : {
                "geo_distance" : {
                    "distance" : "20km",
                    "Location" : {
                        "lat" : 12.958487287824958,
                        "lon" : 77.69648881178146
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting an error saying: 
**failed to find geo_point field [Location]]; }]",**

Please help me regarding this. Also, if possible also guide me on how to do faceted search on this data, to show clinics within a range of distance: like between 20 and 30 kilometers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reverse your ordering. PUT your mapping mapping first and then do the bulk insert.

By putting the map before the insert you are letting ES know what the datatype are so that it can index them correctly. ES allows you to add mappings to an existing index but the data that's already there isn't going to get re-indexed automatically. (This is a known issue).